# Android Push notification generated by broadcast intent filter replace with old notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

i am working on one project when i am put message then i am send it as notification to another user using broadcast it working fine but when i am send again new message then replace with old notification not create new notification

below is my code for generate notification

```
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

inboxStyle.addLine(message);

Notification notification;
notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setSound(alarmSound)
        .setStyle(inboxStyle)
        .setColor(color)
        .setSmallIcon(setNotificationIcon(mBuilder))
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
        .setContentText(message)
        .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Broadcast code

```
public class IncomingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(CUSTOM_INTENT)) {

            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            String chat_id = intent.getStringExtra("chat_id");
            String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
            String chatType = intent.getStringExtra("chatType");
            MyFirebaseMessagingService mMyFirebaseMessagingService = new MyFirebaseMessagingService();
            Log.e("CHATID BROADCADST",chat_id);
            Intent mIntent1;
            if(chatType.equalsIgnoreCase("group")){
                mIntent1=new Intent(context,ActivityChatMyGroup.class);
            }else {
                mIntent1=new Intent(context,ActivityChat.class);
            }
            Bundle mBundle=new Bundle();
            mBundle.putString("name",username);
            mIntent1.putExtras(mBundle);
            mMyFirebaseMessagingService.showChatNotificationMessage(context, chat_id, username, message, mIntent1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: notificationManager.notify((int) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), notification); try using this method replace last line with above line

Comment: change notificationid each time

Answer (score 2):

You should increment Config.NOTIFICATION_ID each time notifications is shown. If two notifications have same notifications id then previous notification will be replaced.

Maintains a variable (static or preference based etc) and increment it in your method

//Preference

```
int notificationId = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt("Notification_ID", 0);

notificationId++;
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (context).edit().putInt("Notification_ID", notificationId).apply();
```

**And then use this variable**

```
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: i am do that also but it repeat multiple time

Comment: How does it repeat If you increment it?

Comment: I am updating answer, wait

Comment: above code not working give 4 notification on single message

Comment: That means you are showing 4 notifications against a message.

Comment: yes showing 4 notification against because my broadcast on receive call 4 time

Comment: Please post your broadcast? We receive one broadcast for single SMS.

Comment: Broadcast receiver looks fine. Which means actual broadcast is being sent 4 times. Can you please show me code where sendBroadcast is called?

Comment: Is your app sending broadcast or any library?